# How can I size the dumping rate for an Reaction Control Thrusters?

Tags: attitude, reaction-wheel

I am designing an interplanetary mission that will last 20 years (14 year to arrive, 6 year science around Neptune).

I will use Reaction wheel (RW) to change the attitude of the spacecraft.

The problem is that the RW need some thrusters to desaturate.

Using a monopropellant engine (hydrazine), how can I estimate the desaturation per day that I need to be sure that RWs will work properly for the whole mission?

Comment: Before you can answer how to estimate the desaturation, you need to estimate the saturation.   What are all the sources of external torques on your spacecraft? At Neptune i'm guessing (no math was harmed) magnetic torques and gravity gradient torques will be largest.  If low enough drag will also create torques.  Solar pressure needs to be considered around earth but likely too weak at Neptune (although you may need to consider it in cruise).

Comment: To estimate the sizes of those, can you explain a little more about the size and mass of your spacecraft and how close it will orbit Neptune? Does it have very, very large solar panels for power, or does it (hopefully) use an on-board RTG?

Comment: It uses RTG on boar. the dimensions are like cassini (a bit more heavy and big). 7,000 kg mass at launch, moment of inertia Ix = Iy = 10,000 kg*m^2 Iz = 5000 kg*m^2

he will be at 250,000 km from surface (pericenter). The orbiter will perform Triton Flyby each 25 days and it will pass 100 km from Triton surface.

The largest disturbance is the gravity gradient of Neptune and gravity gradient of Triton (10^-3)

Magnetic and Atmospheric Torque is really low with respect to the gravity gradient.